# grep: filtering list with multiple special characters

Tags: regex, grep, filtering

Using grep or another command line tool I need to filter a list so that every line containing one or more of the following characters are excluded:

```
.
/
-
'
[space]
```

I'm having a hard time escaping special characters while searching for multiple expesseions.

This isn't working:

```
grep -v '(.|/|-|'| )' input > output
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `grep` command uses "Basic" regular expression format.  The regex you've written is in "Extended" format.  You can tell grep to use extended format with the `-E` option.

You've included a dot in your regex.  Remember that a dot matches "any" character.  To escape its normal behaviour you can either escape it with a backslash (`\.`) or by putting it in a range (`[.]`).  I prefer the latter notation because I find that backslashes make things more difficult to read.  The choice is yours.

You have a single quote in your expression.  As you've written it, the command line won't work because the embedded single quote exits the string begun with the first single quote. You can get around this by wrapping your regex in double quotes.

You also don't need the outer brackets with this regex.

So... You could write the whole thing in Basic notation:

```
grep -v "[.]\|/\|-\|'\| " input > output
```

Or you could write it in Extended notation:

```
grep -Ev "[.]|/|-|'| " input > output
```

Or alternately, you could put ALL these characters into a range, which is written the same way in Basic and Extended:

```
grep -v "[./' -]" input > output
```

Note that the hyphen has moved to the END of the range so that it won't be interpreted as "the range of characters between a forward slash and a single quote".  Note also that since this range is also compatible with Basic RE notation, I've removed the `-E` option.

See [`man re_format(7)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format) for details.